# Do .py Python files contain metadata?

Tags: python, metadata

.doc files, .pdf files, and some image formats all contain metadata about the file, such as the author.

Is a .py file just a plain text file whose contents are all visible once opened with a code editor like Sublime, or does it also contain metadata? If so, how does one access this metadata?

Comment: Have you tried opening a python file with a text editor to find out?

Comment: I don't think .py files contain metadata. What made you suspect so?

Comment: Python files (`*.py`) are text files as vast majority of source code files. There are also compiled files (`*.pyc`) having compiled bytecode, but no metadata like author.

Comment: It's not an unreasonable question, especially if you're interested in Python+Security.  And if you're on an OS that misguidedly tries to hide essential information from you at every turn.

Comment: @Brian Of course I did. Except I'm making sure there's not anything that's not visible to a text editor. A non-sophisticated user of PDFs wouldn't know there's tons of embedded data in a PDF either, so I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted.

Comment: If you count a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as metadata, then yes, but it is metadata that's visible in a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux and most Unixes, .py's are just text (sometimes unicode text).

On Windows and Mac, there are cubbyholes where you can stash data, but I doubt Python uses them.

.pyc's, on the other hand, have at least a little metadata stuff in them - or so I've heard.  Specifically: there's supposed to be a timestamp in them, so that if you copy a filesystem hierarchy, python won't automatically recreate all the .pyc's on import.  There may or may not be more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So my particular case is on Windows, is there anything specific I should look for in these "cubbyholes"?

Comment: Try: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams